# Android Alarm Manager inconsistent for 4.4.x.What is the alternative solution to support minSDKVersion 9 and targetSdkVersion 21

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-4.4-kitkat

My task is to call the service for every 24hours and above based on the settings...

The following code perfectly works for 5 minutes, 2 hours but not working for long hours like 24 hours and above in Moto E 4.4.4, samsung S4 4.4.2 and Nexus5 4.5..

The following code even not working for 5 minutes in Xiaomi Mi3 4.4.2 , also alarm is not present in the alarm dump..

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    am2.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 86400000, pi);
} else {
    am2.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 86400000, pi);
}
```

My Build Settings :-
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" 
        using  4.4.2 sdk to build apk...

After checking the API reference i came to know that alarm is inconsistence from Android 4.4x and above...
How to make exact alarm compatible from minSdkVersion 9 to 19 and above.
I spend more time to analyse and debug since i have to wait for 24hours and more to check the alarm service call.
Providing hints or solution would be very helpful and appreciated

"
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html
Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.
Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested. "

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider using [GcmNetworkManager](https://goo.gl/E3qX0U) or, even better, this library that abstracts the job scheduling: https://github.com/evernote/android-job